# How to change font color of selected row in datagrid WPF C# when using context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, contextmenu

I am developing a WPF Application using Mahapps.Metro library.

There is a DataGrid where I want to use a ContextMenu on the added rows, for that I am defining this in datagrid resources

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="RowMenu" 
        DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem Header="Borrar detalle" Click="delete_Click" />
        <MenuItem Header="Editar detalle" Click="edit_Click" />
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

and adding that context menu in the rowstyle

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" >
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

The problem with this is that when user clicks on the row, it seems to disappear (the font color turns white).
I tried adding the following to the rowstyle but it does not seems to work.

```
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" >
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

MY last option is to use the contextmenu in the grid instead rows, but I want to know if there is something I can do to make this work.
Hope you can help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use based-on feature on your defined style:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}" />
</Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not seems to work, I added that to the code but the row still getting white when is selected.